# What's the significance of the flashbacks?

Tags: analysis, high-lane

In [High Lane](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1433562/combined) (2009) or Vertige, Fanny Valette's character has a few flashbacks. What's the importance of this flashback scene? How is it related to the film?

Comment: could you add some details about the flashback scene?